# Add class name into div in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

i using Alert components i need to insert class name like `animated zoomIn` into the div near `<div class="alert-wrapper"></div>`

it's possible ?[image]

```
doAlert() {
      let alert = Alert.create({
        cssClass: 'animated zoomIn',
        title: 'New Friend!',
        message: 'Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just approved your friend request!',
        buttons: ['Ok']
      });
      this.nav.present(alert);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want some custom too then try this 
Simply create your alert like this:

```
let alertPopup = Alert.create({
title: 'title',
subTitle: 'message',
cssClass: 'animated_zoomIn',
buttons: [{
text: 'btnType',
cssClass: 'buttoncss'
}]
});
this.nav.present(alertPopup);

In your app.core.scss or your page scss, define your cssClass like this:

.buttoncss{
color:#e74c3c;
/*Any other style you wish to apply*/
}

.animated_zoomIn{
color:#e74c3c;
/*Any other style you wish to apply*/
}

----Make sure your page scss is imported----
```

Comment: thank i .animatedZoomIn {
  .alert-wrapper {
    extend .animated;
    extend .zoomIn;

  }
} working fine

Comment: fine .you were using space in class so it is showing other class name .That's y it was not working ,